# Get return code from linux command in C program

Tags: c, unix, exit-code

I am basically trying to check if a particular file exists or not. For that I am using the test command of Unix.

```
 sprintf(execbuf, "%s if test -r %s ; then true; else exit; fi;",
         execbuf, st->file, NO_FILE);
```

It works fine, but I do not want to exit if the file is not here, rather it should return FAIL.

I am not able to figure out how to make the program return FAIL. I was thinking of using the exit code from the above command, but still I am not able to figure out how to use that exit code outside the Linux command in the program.

Comment: Wouldn't it be far easier to use the `stat()` function? Or `access()`?

Comment: Based on your comment to my suggested solution, You're saying you're trying to run shell scripting via C code and want to ascertain the result of that?

Comment: When did `sprintf()` gain the ability to execute a program?

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend you rather just use the [access](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/access.html)() call, and not execute external shell commands to figure this out.

Just be aware that such cases are subject to race conditions - the file might exist when you call access() (or execute a shell command that determines whether the file exists), but it might be gone when you actually need it later on. If that's a problem for you, just open() the file, and use the file descriptor later on when you actually need it for I/O.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not married to what your doing right now, then I'd suggest using stat:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv[])
{
  struct stat sts;
  if (stat(argv[1], &sts) == -1 && errno == ENOENT)
      printf ("The file %s doesn't exist...\n", argv [1]);
  else
      printf("The file exists\n");
```

This will tell you if it exists or not. If you dont' want to pass it command line, parameter 1 is a const char*, so just pass it the file name.

Comment: The problem with stat is that we need to pass an absolute path to it. But in a case where I am doing $HOME/file.sh, stat will return -1 even if the file is there.

Comment: You don't need to pass an absolute path to it at all. Things like `~/file.txt` will even work.

Comment: The `stat` call doesn't require an absolute path, a relative one will do. However, it does require a valid path - it won't do tilde or variable expansion for you, so neither `$HOME/foo` nor `~/foo` will work.

Comment: Really? cause it works on my system... `mike@linux-4puc:~> ./a.out ~/test.txt`
`The file exists`

Comment: @Mike That works because the shell expands ~/test.txt before passing it to your program. (try e.g. `echo ~/test.txt` ) Note also that your test is bogus, if for whatever reason stat() returns -1, you cannot conclude that the file exist. (e.g. errno might be ENOTDIR and other stuff)